# How does Australia's National Cabinet differ from COAG?

Tags: government, covid-19, australia, cabinet

As a response to the Covid-19 pandemic, Australia [formed](https://www.pm.gov.au/media/press-conference-premiers-and-chief-ministers-parramatta-nsw) a National Cabinet on March 13th, consisting of the Prime Minister and the premiers and chief ministers of the Australian states and territories. As far as I can see, this is extremely similar to the existing [Council of Australian Governments](https://www.coag.gov.au/) (COAG), the "peak intergovernmental forum in Australia". The only difference in membership, at least, is that the President of the Australian Local Government Association is not a member of the National Cabinet.

How does the National Cabinet differ from COAG? Is it more of a formal government coalition like, for example, a National Government/Government of National Unity?

Comment: It appears to me the National "Cabinet" is a *temporary* intergovernmental forum that focuses on the coordination of responses to COVID-19 (by different executives at federal and state level), and by no means is it an actual executive organ. It is limited in purpose and temporary in time. COAG is a more standing mechanism by meet far less often and deals with a wide variety of topics.

Comment: @zhantongz how is that NOT an answer?

Comment: @CGCampbell I am not that familiar with Australian politics, if anyone from Australia can confirm it would be better.